# PHP MVC: How to avoid calling model layer functions in views

Tags: php, model-view-controller, kohana

I'm using MVC pattern in my project,I want to implement MVC in my project perfectly without any loop holes.I've following situation my application,

```
  foreach($std_results as $std_result)
   {
      $std_name = ORM::factory('students')->where('id',$std_result->hall_ticket_number);//I want to avoid this     
       //other stuff follows from here
   }
```

The above code which I've shown is from view,I've fetched total records based on some conditions in controller and I've passed result to view,there again I got a situation where I want to communicate with model based on obtained records.I don't want to even call model layer function there,how can I avoid this,I'm using Kohana framework in my application.Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: If you are using MVC design pattern, then view should be requesting information from model layer. And no, "model layer" is not a different name for "ORM".

Answer (score 1):

1) You need to have a model class for students:

```
class Student extends ORM
{
   public function your_function()
   {
      // Do the DB stuff here
   }
}
```

2) Call the method from the controller and pass the result to the view:

```
// ...
$std_results = ORM::factory('student')->your_function();
// ...
$view->bind('std_results', $std_results);
// ...
```